# Autlo Layout issue

Tags: swift, autolayout

Set programatacally autlo layout to UIView but not set height constraint. I can't identify what is issue.

```
let viewSep = UIView()
            viewSep.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            viewSep.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewInner.addSubview(viewSep)

            viewSep.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewInner.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            viewSep.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblDate.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
            viewSep.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewInner.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            viewSep.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21)
```

Comment: You aren't setting `isActive = true` on the height constraint

Comment: @dan Thank. I forgot this.